# How do I get numbers before and after a colon within a cell in Calc?

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have some cells which contain times entered in by users, which are written in the following format: `mm:ss`. There are never any hours. The seconds always have leading zeroes. The minutes may or may not have leading zeros.

Because I need to separate out the minutes and seconds for various operations, I need to be able to get at the numbers before and after the colon.

How do I select the number before a colon in a cell, and how do I select the number after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use the internal time functions [`MINUTE()`](http://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/MINUTE) and [`SECOND()`](http://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/SECOND). They're designed to get the minute/second component from a time value.

**Edit:**
Actually, if you've got a problem with users entering the incorrect time format, the solution is not quite as simple as I wrote in the comment, but it's still fairly close:

```
 =CONCATENATE("0:",HOUR(F421),":",MINUTE(A1))
```

This basically shifts each time component one unit to the right. The hours become minutes, the minutes become seconds.

You *could* use the `FIND()`, `LEN()`, `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()` functions to do string manipulations and re-implement the time functions you need, but you'd essentially be fighting the software rather than working with it. And in the long run, you always get more done working *with* the software rather than against it.

If you still want to do it that way, it'd basically be something like:

**Minute:**

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND(":", A1), -1)
```

**Second:**

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND(":", A1))
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that doesn't help me extract the minutes and seconds from the format `mm:ss`. I can not change the input format, so if there's a way those functions can take `mm:ss` and return the minutes, please be more specific.

Comment: @Dave: It doesn't matter what format the time is in as long as it's a LibreOffice recognized time format. If that cell is set to display numbers in a time format, and it has a value that Calc is able to display, then `MINUTE()` and `SECOND()` will extract the minute/second components.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it that way, but now I'm having trouble with the time format and input. I set the format of the cell to `MM:SS`, and then tested it by entering `4:00`, and it displayed `00:00:00`.

Comment: @Dave: That's because `4:00` to Calc is `4:00:00`. If you want Calc to actually recognize it as `00:04:00`, then you need to type that. Otherwise, none of your cells will have the correct values, and you won't be able to use any of Calc's time functions. In which case, you may as well set the display mode to "text", and then you'll have to write your own time parsing/calculation functions. But that's essentially re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I think I'll have to do that, because in my situation I can't impose upon the users entering the times to do it in 00:00:00 format. It's too bad Calc is too restrictive about how time has to be entered, but I'd rather modify calc than modify people. Still, +1 for trying to help. :)

Comment: @Dave: It's not just Calc. It's every spreadsheet program out there. `##:##` is ambiguous, and the most useful way to parse it is as HH:MM, so that is the convention in most countries. To do otherwise would require retraining millions of people. It makes more sense to simply fix your spreadsheets, which could be easily done by writing a macro or formula to append a "0:" in front of those time values. Insisting on sticking with incorrect date values to take some kind of moral stance against users having to learn how to properly use spreadsheet software is a bit silly IMO.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the *input* cell to automatically append `00:` to the value entered by the user? And have it not be visible?

Comment: @Dave M G: You could definitely do that via scripting. I can try to find a VB script solution later. But the simpler solution might be to just keep the original input values on a separate sheet so that your main display/calculation sheet only has the `00:`-appended values.

Comment: Okay, I've got it now. I took the user inputted value, copied it over to another cell, concatenated `00:` as you suggested, then acted on the new column with the time functions. I also had to use some of the text formatting functions to get the look I wanted for the users, but the bottom line is that I created the extra step to convert to time, and then worked from that. Thanks for your help!